# Error with Storybook: Can't resolve 'react-chartjs-2'

Tags: next.js, storybook, react-chartjs-2

I am using **react-chartjs-2** in my **next.js** project and it works well when running the project. However, when I try to run **Storybook**, I get this error:

```
    ERROR in ./components/common/Chart/Chart.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-chartjs-2' in '/project/components/common/Chart'
     @ ./components/common/Chart/Chart.tsx 7:0-38 25:32-35
     @ ./components/common/Chart/index.ts
     @ ./components/common/index.ts
     @ ./common/theme/stories/Colors.stories.tsx
     @ ./common/theme/stories sync nonrecursive ^\.[\\/](?:(?!\.)(?=.)[^/]*?\.stories\.tsx)$
    
    ERROR in ./node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js 561:17
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (561:17)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    |     };
    | class DatasetController {
    >  static defaults = {};
    |  static datasetElementType = null;
    |  static dataElementType = null;
     @ ./components/common/Chart/Chart.tsx 8:0-73 10:0-5 10:15-28 10:30-41 10:43-53
     @ ./components/common/Chart/index.ts
     @ ./components/common/index.ts
     @ ./common/theme/stories/Colors.stories.tsx
     @ ./common/theme/stories sync nonrecursive ^\.[\\/](?:(?!\.)(?=.)[^/]*?\.stories\.tsx)$
     @ ./generated-stories-entry.js
```

This is the Chart component.

```
import { Box } from '@components';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
  Chart, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement,
} from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement);
const labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [...],
    borderWidth: 1,
  }],
};

const ChartContainer = () => (
  <Box>
    <Bar
      data={data}
      options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      }}
    />
  </Box>
);

export default ChartContainer;
```

In my package.json, I have

- "chart.js": "^4.0.1"
- "react-chartjs-2": "^5.0.1"
- "next": "^11.1.2"
- "storybook": "^6.5.6"
- "react": "^17.0.0"

Why is it giving me this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same two issues as well.

**First Error**

the first one you have is that storybook can't find the `react-chartjs-2` module:

I resolved it by updating storybooks `main.js` file. Under the `WebpackFinal` I added a alias for `react-chartjs-2` that looks like this

```js
// project/.storybook/main.js

'react-chartjs-2': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/react-chartjs-2/dist/index.js')
```

**Second Error**

The second one you have is that storybook doesn't know how to parse `static defaults = {}` in `chart.js`

I resolved this by updating storybooks `main.js` to include the `framework` and `core` properties.

```
// project/.storybook/main.js

framework: '@storybook/react',
core: {
  builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5'
}
```

I also had to install the packages listed below

```
@storybook/builder-webpack5
@storybook/manager-webpack5
```

After those changes I was able to run storybook and view my charts. Figured out the second answer by making a new project and installing storybook and chart.js into it so that the only thing was a chart component then I compared the differences between that projects config vs my other projects config.

I hope that helps.